# CocoaPods 'framework not found FBLPromises' while reducing podfile sizes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, cocoapods

I have an ios app using swiftui, CocoaPods, Firebase, and AdMob. I need to back up to tell the story. My app is a french verb conjugation built with only a couple of advantages over the competition: app size and speed. The app is very compact. I realized I needed money to put the app on the store and so I downloaded AdMob. AdMob brought my app from 2MB to 40MB.

### Actual Problem

But I found a way to only include parts of AdMob that I needed. This was to comment out the following in the podfile: `use_frameworks!`. I was told that doing this would reduce Pod sizes.

### Steps I've taken

1. I followed their instructions and commented out lines: `#use_frameworks!`
2. I quit Xcode
3. I deleted pod files.
4. in terminal I typed `pod install`
5. I opened the code workspace
6. I ran the code
7. the build immediately failed
8. I looked around StackOverflow and google for answers and i could not find any that solved my problem

### Relevant code

Pods file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘10.0’

# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

target 'French Words Remastered' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for French Words Remastered

  target 'French Words RemasteredTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'French Words RemasteredUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you producing a Debug or Release build to evaluate the app size? Do consider that the former can take a lot more in size than the latter, and that App Store does a lot of thinning and optimization to reduce app size for you.

Comment: I have built with both, I have used the aggressive size optimization settings, tried only importing the functions I need, and uninstalled it and reinstalled it. (all to try and fix the size issue)

Comment: please I need an answer to this question...